# Trouble figuring out JavaScript performance issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to write an item locator in jquery. Basically, I have a table of ~350 items. Each item has 3 things: an item name, a code, and a unit size. **Each row in the table has the class "item", and in each row, the  has the class "dcode", "item-name", or "unit-size" to describe the data it's showing**

I'd like to put an input search field at the top so that there's a live search of the rows in the table. There can be multiple tables on a page, but only one is visible at a time (there are tabs that select which table is shown). So I'd like to have one input field that looks for the visible table and then searches it.

Here's an example table:

```
<table>
  <tr class="item">
       <td class="item-name">Item name #1</td>
       <td class="code">001</td>
       <td class="unit-size">100ml</td>
  </tr
</table>
```

And here's my javascript

```
$(function(){

  var $itemsFoundCount = $("#itemsFound #count");

  if($(".nav-tabs").length !== 0) {

    $(".nav-tabs, .nav-tabs li a").click(function(){

      $("#itemFilter").val('').keyup();

      // Wait until view updates to count...      
      setTimeout(function() {
        $itemsFoundCount.html($(".item:visible").length); 

      }, 0);

    });
  }

  $("#itemFilter").keyup(function(){
    var filter = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    var $allItems = $(".table:visible .item");

    if(filter === '') {
      $allItems.show();
      $itemsFoundCount.html($allItems.length);
      repaintRows();
      return;
    }

    $allItems.each(function(){
      var itemName = $(this).find('.item-name').html().toLowerCase(),
      code = $(this).find('.code').html().toLowerCase(),
      unitSize = $(this).find('.unit-size').html().toLowerCase(), itemType;

      if(itemName.indexOf(filter) == -1 && code.indexOf(filter) == -1 && unitSize.indexOf(filter) == -1) {
        $(this).hide();
      }
      else {
        $(this).show();
      }

    });

    $itemsFoundCount.html($(".item:visible").length);

  });

});
```

itemFilter is an input with id="itemFilter"

This works great on desktop computers, but on iPads and phones it's ridiculously slow.

What could I do to make this run faster?

Thanks!

Comment: The only potential optimization I can see is to use a local variable `var $this = $(this)`, so you don't call that function repeatedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all your searches query the dom. this takes time and performs bad.

on application start copy your table data into an array and perform the search there.

you can either populate the array from the table like:

```
var data = new Array();
```

than iterate over all the table's rows and fill the data like this

```
data.push([item-name, code, unit-size]);
```

or load the data through other means (json) and create the table from the data. this way you would have less data transfered over the wire, because the json file does not contain all the redundant html tags for each row.

later do your search algorith on the data. the position of the entry are the same as the table rows. for example jQuery selector nth-child to find access the row.

an better performing approach would be to save a reference to the row's in the data aswell:

```
data.push([THE_ROW, item-name, code, unit-size]);
```

this way you can directly address them without searching for them in the DOM every time.

have in mind that THE_ROW has to be a jQuery element for jQuery methods to work. you can create a jQuery Element from a HTMLElement like this: `$(htmlElement)`